# red Undefined message when creating product category woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories, development-environment

I’m developing a site locally using Wamp.

When creating a Category I enter Name, Slug, Description and Image, choosing “Standard” as display type.

When clicking “Add New Category” a message in Red appears at the top of the screen saying “Undefined”.

The new category doesn’t appear until I navigate away from the page and click to view it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first deactivating all plugins and then seeing if the problem still occurs.

If the problem doesn't occur anymore you'll need to gradually re-enable plugins until it happens again, and then try to update the problem plugin or contact the plugin developers.

A similar question was asked [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-a-category-it-shows-undefined-with-php-7-2/), and the problem was caused by the WooCommerce Wholesale plugin.